# How reverse the order of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently use this bit of javascript inside Adobe After Effects to print a customizable list of numbers

```
x = 0 //starting point (the first number in the list);
y= 20 //increments (the size of the steps);
z= 5 //the number of steps;

Array.from(new Array(z)).map((_, i) => i * y + x).join("\n")
```

which (in this case) would output

```
0
20
40
60
80
```

It would be really cool if I could also generate the list in reverse

```
80
60
40
20
0
```

but because I'm not a programmer I have no idea how to do this. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: You might not be a programmer, but can't you Google it?!

Comment: there is a .reverse()

Comment: thats the problem. I know absolutely nothing about programming so vage suggestions and code snippets that would be enough in most cases dont really help me. I tried to copy paste some of the stuff from google into the code but with 0 knowledge its impossible (at least for me) to get something to work.

Comment: Why not simply do `Array.from(new Array(z)).map((_, i) => (z - 1 - i) * y).join("\n")`?

Answer (score -1):

Instead of starting from the *first* number (`x`) and adding `y` for each iteration, you can start from the *last* number and subtract `y` for every iteration.

The last number would be the number of times `y` is added added to `x`. That gives the formulat `(z - 1) * y) + x`

```js
x = 0 //starting point (the first number in the list);
y= 20 //increments (the size of the steps);
z= 5 //the number of steps;

const result = Array.from(new Array(z))
  .map((_, i) => (((z - 1) * y) + x) - (i * y)).join("\n");
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think there is no need to optimisation here, as the op has no programming experience, a simple solution is well enough, which would be the `Array.reverse()`.

See the the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) for correct usage.

```js
const x = 0 //starting point (the first number in the list);
const y= 20 //increments (the size of the steps);
const z= 5 //the number of steps;

const array = Array.from({length: z}, ((_, i) => i * y + x)).reverse().join("\n");

console.log(array);
```

**Another possible solution**: simply populate your array from the back. Then no need to reverse.

```js
 const x = 0 //starting point (the first number in the list);
    const y= 20 //increments (the size of the steps);
    const z= 5 //the number of steps;

    const array = Array.from({length: z}, ((_, i) => (z * y - y) - i * y)).join("\n");

    console.log(array);
```

Comment: Thanks but why be so cryptic. I tried 
Array.reverse.from(new Array(z)).map((_, i) => i * y + x).join("\n") and
Array.reverse.(new Array(z)).map((_, i) => i * y + x).join("\n")
both didnt work. so how do I use this correctly.